# Error Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 after installing VS2015 in W10

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

After installing VS2015 in W10, and trying to compile a project which works perfectly in W7, I´m getting this error: Unsupported major.minor version 52.0.

I tried to installa Java7U80, Java7U79, Java8, changing classpath, and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple JDKs then remove them. Install JDK 8 the latest version and go to Visual Studio options => Xamrin and set the `Java Development Kit Location` to the JDK 8 path e.g `C:\Java\JDK\jdk1.8.0_92`.

[image: Updating the Java Development Kit Location in the Visual Studio Xamarin.Android options]

Answer (score 0):

Usually this error comes up, when your project compiles/runs against lets say Java 7, while referencing some dependency which is compiled against Java 8 (and uses Java 8 features).
Check your compiler level or your runtime configuration.